# Showing a popup from a util service in Angular

Tags: angular, service, popup

I have a custom component *popup.component.ts* and I use it in each of my views' markup. It sits at the bottom being invisible. When I want to pop up a message, I just switch the bound field to *this.poppyVisible = true* and it shows.

I realized that I never have separate popups so it would make sense to add a method to my existing *util.service.ts* file that does the popping for me. But I get unsure if I can do that at all and if so, if I have to pass a reference to a view child or something.

Googling the issue leads to a lot of Material stuff showing that approach and that doesn't really enlightens me on my issue. There are other that build a whole service but one way or the other, they rely on 3rd party popups.

I only need to know how a general approach should be lain out. I fear that following hte wrong blog might lead me to bad habits.

Is it possible to have a service popup a component in a view? What should I google for to avoid the default Material/Kendo things that are clouding the view?

**edit**

Based on the comment, I feel I might clarify that I've done the research giving me suggestions on [Angular CDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52294857/1525840) that sounds like the only option. I just feel I'm not certain that I actually got it right. I've found [this blog](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-dynamic-components/) that comes closely but has way too much overhead to filter out my answer, at least on my skill level.

Comment: If you can create a minimal example of what you are trying to achieve using stackblitz or similar it should be easier to help

Comment: @chrismclarke My question is **literally** if it's possible to choose strategy A or if I'm stuck on strategy B. I'll gladly produce a range of example on Blitzy but at this stage I have no idea what you'd like to see there. Would you give me a few pointers on what you'd need to see to be able to help?

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand the question fully. Can you have a 'popup service' as it were, some sort of lightweight service you can call from anywhere to show a popup? Well yes, this is what angular do with their dialogs/toasts etc., various packages such as toastr has its ways as does react does with portals.

Comment: Although where I get confused is 'in a view'. I mean, does it have to be part of the template or could it just sit outside (like in the main app component), and be triggered from a view (like how you might open/close a side menu)

Comment: @chrismclarke Aha, there we go. Your comments in combination with the reading I've done just hit me on how to proceed. It's a bit intangible but it was precisely what I needed to see. I think I got it now. And further improvement can be done using the answer below. But it wasn't the answer that tipped me in the right direction. Thanks, mate.

Comment: Most welcome, yes it's a little counter-intuitive because although you see it sitting inside a view it will actually be on the dom outside. But glad you've got what you need working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with help of rxjs Subject Observable. We can able to open a popup from utilservice. Create 'showPopup' and 'hidePopup' as 2 utils methods. These methods will emit subject observable, so observers (in popup.component.ts) can receive and act on it.

**utils.service.ts**

```
private openPopup = new Subject();
public openPopupObservable = this.openPopup.asObservable();

showPopup(){
  this.openPopup.next(true);
}

hidePopup(){
  this.openPopup.next(false);
}
```

**popup.component.ts**

```
constructor(private utils: utilsService){}
ngOnInit(){
   this.utils.openPopupObservable.subscribe(isActive=>{
      this.poppyVisible = isActive
   });
}
```